# Vlc Does not start

Tags: 16.04, vlc, qt, plugins, qt5

so I am running into a lot of problems with vlc these days. I had removed qt5 to solve the trimming error but ended up destroying the Vlc build. now when I click vlc icon it doesn't do anything

Anybody with any input please share...

below is the error code if I try to start from terminal

```
freak@freak-lenovo:~/Downloads$ vlc
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
[00000000023ac148] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: The error messages says: **Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.** - did you try it?

Comment: And don't "remove qt5" :)

Comment: yes.. i have completely removed vlc by running apt-get autoremove vlc, apt-get remove vlc-nox and reinstalled it... but still no luck